# Exchange different arrays elements in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is there any ruby method that I can use to replace two different arrays elements?
For instance, I have these two arrays:

```
#Before exchange
arr_one = [1,2,3,4,5]
arr_two = ["some", "thing", "new"]
```

After replacements the elements I am expecting something like this:

```
#After exchange
arr_one = ["some", "thing", "new"]
arr_two = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I handle this with or without a ruby method?

Comment: This question not make sense. You're asking about array elements but in the example you are swapping the entire array. Whats the point?

Answer (score 5):

You  mean, you want to 'exchange' values of local variables? It's quite easy in Ruby:

```
arr_one, arr_two = arr_two, arr_one
```

Comment: Dennis, this is called "[multiple assignment](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)" or "parallel assignment".

Answer (score 4):

If you need to have the arrays stay put (i.e. the values of the variables not change) and exchange the *contents*, then this should do:

```
arr_tmp = arr_one.dup
arr_one.replace(arr_two)
arr_two.replace(arr_tmp)
```

Comment: ...or `arr_one[0..-1] = arr_two; arr_two[0..-1] = arr_tmp`.